# ASP.NET core Image file validation error. How can I validated a ImageFile?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have ASP.NET core razor page to introduce people to a SQL database. Everything was working well until a new byte[] imagefile was incorporate to de SQL database. Since that, the web page break at ModelState.IsValid .
I have a core Razor page, but when I Have add a Imagefile field to the sql database the validation break. Before add the FotoT field, everything worked well. How can I do to validate this field as the others? Here is my code:

```
@page
@model HojaFiliacion.Pages.ListaPacientes.CrearModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Crear";
}

<br />
<h2 class="text-info">Crear Nuevo Paciente</h2>

<div class="border">
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger">
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Nombre"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Nombre" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.Nombre" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Apellido1"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Apellido1" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.Apellido1" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Apellido2"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Apellido2" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.Apellido2" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.fNacimiento"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.fNacimiento" type="date" style="width: 200px;" value="@DateTime.Today" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.fNacimiento" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Nif"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Nif" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.Nif" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.sexo"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select asp-for="DatosFiliacion.sexo" class="form-control">
                            <option value="F">Femenino</option>
                            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.idEstado"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select asp-for="DatosFiliacion.idEstado" class="form-control">
                            <option value="1">Soltero/a</option>
                            <option value="2">Casado/a</option>
                            <option value="3">Divorciado/a</option>
                            <option value="4">Separado/a</option>
                            <option value="5">En pareja</option>
                            <option value="6">Viudo/a</option>
                            <option value="7">Pareja de hecho</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>





            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Domicilio"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Domicilio" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.Domicilio" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Poblacion"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.Poblacion" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.Poblacion" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.CP"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.CP" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.CP" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.idProvincia"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select asp-for="DatosFiliacion.idProvincia" class="form-control">
                            <option value='1'>Álava</option>
                            <option value='2'>A Coruña</option>
                            <option value='3'>Albacete</option>
                            <option value='4'>Alicante/Alacant</option>
                            <option value='5'>Almería</option>
                            <option value='6'>Asturias</option>
                            <option value='7'>Ávila</option>
                            <option value='8'>Badajoz</option>
                            <option value='9'>Illes Balears</option>
                            <option value='10' selected>Barcelona</option>
                            <option value='11'>Burgos</option>
                            <option value='12'>Cáceres</option>
                            <option value='13'>Cádiz</option>
                            <option value='14'>Cantabria</option>
                            <option value='15'>Castellón/Castelló</option>
                            <option value='16'>Ceuta</option>
                            <option value='17'>Ciudad Real</option>
                            <option value='18'>Córdoba</option>
                            <option value='19'>Cuenca</option>
                            <option value='20'>Girona</option>
                            <option value='21'>Granada</option>
                            <option value='22'>Guadalajara</option>
                            <option value='23'>Guipúzcoa</option>
                            <option value='24'>Huelva</option>
                            <option value='25'>Huesca</option>
                            <option value='26'>Jaén</option>
                            <option value='27'>La Rioja</option>
                            <option value='28'>Las Palmas</option>
                            <option value='29'>León</option>
                            <option value='30'>Lleida</option>
                            <option value='31'>Lugo</option>
                            <option value='32'>Madrid</option>
                            <option value='33'>Málaga</option>
                            <option value='34'>Melilla</option>
                            <option value='35'>Murcia</option>
                            <option value='36'>Navarra</option>
                            <option value='37'>Ourense</option>
                            <option value='38'>Palencia</option>
                            <option value='39'>Pontevedra</option>
                            <option value='40'>Salamanca</option>
                            <option value='41'>Santa Cruz de Tenerife</option>
                            <option value='42'>Segovia</option>
                            <option value='43'>Sevilla</option>
                            <option value='44'>Soria</option>
                            <option value='45'>Tarragona</option>
                            <option value='46'>Teruel</option>
                            <option value='47'>Toledo</option>
                            <option value='48'>Valencia/Valéncia</option>
                            <option value='49'>Valladolid</option>
                            <option value='50'>Vizcaya</option>
                            <option value='51'>Zamora</option>
                            <option value='52'>Zaragoza</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.idProvincia" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.idPaisISO3166"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select asp-for="DatosFiliacion.idPaisISO3166" class="form-control">
                            <option value="4">Afghanistan</option>
                           ....
                            <option value="716">Zimbabwe</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.idPaisISO3166" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.eMail"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.eMail" oninput="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.eMail" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.TelefonoM"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.TelefonoM" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.TelefonoM" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.TelefonoF"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.TelefonoF" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.TelefonoF" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

     
        
        <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.LOPD"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.LOPD" type="checkbox" />
                        <label>He leído y acepto la política de protección de datos</label>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DatosFiliacion.LOPD" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    </form>


    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.FotoT"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input asp-for="DatosFiliacion.FotoT" class="custom-file-input form-control">
                        <label class="custom-file-label">Haz click para cargar foto</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Volver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>





</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

And my cs file:

Comment: What's the type of `FotoT` on your model?

Comment: Can you show us the `Pacientes` model?

Comment: ´ [Display(Name = "Foto")]
        public byte[] FotoT { get; set; }´

Comment: Isn't it trying to validate FotoT as a Byte while you're inputing a string?

Comment: Can you show us the model, which field is required?

Comment: Now it is working ok:

Comment: ` <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
                  <div class="from-group">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                              <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.FotoT"></label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="custom-file">
                              <input name="File1" type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control">
                              <label class="custom-file-label">Haz click para cargar foto</label
                  ´

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IFormFile` to receive the imagefile submitted by the form. Just do it like your orignal post. Define a sperate property `Upload` to receive it and set `[Required]` attribute on it. Then in your post method, convert Upload to byte[] and fill it to FotoT.

I made a demo based on your codes, you can refer to the below codes.

Model:

```
public class Pacientes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foto")] 
    public byte[] FotoT { get; set; }
    public bool LOPD { get; set; }
}
```

Create.csthml:

```
<h1>Create</h1>

<div class="border">

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div class="container" style="padding:25px;">
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label asp-for="DatosFiliacion.FotoT"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input asp-for="Upload" type="file" class="custom-file-input form-control">
                        <label class="custom-file-label">Haz click para cargar foto</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="from-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-3">
                        <input type="submit" value="Crear" class="btn btn-primary form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Volver</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Create.csthml.cs:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    
    private IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    [Required]
    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile Upload { get; set; }

    private readonly PacientesContext _db;

    public CreateModel(PacientesContext db, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
        _db = db;
    }

    
    [BindProperty]
    public Models.Pacientes DatosFiliacion { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads", Upload.FileName);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            
            await Upload.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            DatosFiliacion.FotoT = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        _db.Add(DatosFiliacion);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]